# H2 parameterize a table of temporary values in a join

Tags: sql, postgresql, h2

In PostgreSQL, I have the following query to verify the existence of rows that have exactly the required combination of fields:

```
SELECT * FROM data 
RIGHT JOIN (VALUES (2,2),(4,6)) AS t (o,p) ON p = set1_value AND o = set2_value 
where id is null;
```

This returns me all combinations in the VALUES list which were not found in the `data` table.

H2 throws a syntax error for this: `t([*]o,p)`

And I don't see a way around it. I've tried starting H2 in postgresql compatibility, didn't work.

Is there another way I can achieve this?

I don't know what the `AS t(o,p)` part of the syntax should be referred to, so I can't search for that term. Looks like a parameterized temporary table or something but that doesn't turn up any answers.

Comment: the `AS t(o,p)` is a table alias for a derived table. And the `values (...)` part is called a "row constructor" (you know that from the `insert` statement)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT * 
FROM data 
RIGHT JOIN 
( 
   select 2 as o, 2 as p
   union all
   select 4, 6
) as t ON p = set1_value AND o = set2_value 
where id is null;
```

Comment: The query in the question **is** standard SQL, but you query is not, because according to the standard `FROM` is mandatory in a `SELECT` statement.

Comment: Really? Wow. Never thought so.

Comment: Thanks for that. Dunno how performant that's going to be when I have it execute on a few thousand possible pre-existing combinations, but we'll see

Comment: Update: `stack depth limit exceeded` is what happened when using a big amount of unions.

Comment: If you have such an amount of combinations it would be better to put them in a table and join to that table.